# Combine 2 event change in 1 worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please advise me how can I have both codes in a sheet? They work perfectly fine individually.

I have tried naming is Macro1 and Macro2 but it's not working. I might not have done it right.

```
'Code 1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If [B28] = "Singapore" Then
Sheets("Singapore (2017)").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("Singapore (2017)").Visible = False
End If

If [B28] = "HongKong" Then
Sheets("Hong Kong (2017)").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("Hong Kong (2017)").Visible = False
End If

If [B28] = "Australia" Then
Sheets("Australia (2017)").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("Australia (2017)").Visible = False
End If

End Sub

'Code 2
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 30 Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Application.Rows("32:33").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
        Application.Rows("32:36").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If

If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 32 Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Application.Rows("33:34").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
        Application.Rows("33:36").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 34 Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Application.Rows("35:36").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
        Application.Rows("35:36").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Can both codes work regardless which is being selected first?

Answer (score 0):

You can include both ifs in one sub:

```
'Code 1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If [B28] = "Singapore" Then
Sheets("Singapore (2017)").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("Singapore (2017)").Visible = False
End If

If [B28] = "HongKong" Then
Sheets("Hong Kong (2017)").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("Hong Kong (2017)").Visible = False
End If

If [B28] = "Australia" Then
Sheets("Australia (2017)").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("Australia (2017)").Visible = False
End If


'Code 2
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 30 Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Application.Rows("32:33").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
        Application.Rows("32:36").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If

If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 32 Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Application.Rows("33:34").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
        Application.Rows("33:36").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 34 Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Application.Rows("35:36").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
        Application.Rows("35:36").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel. However i am receiving this Run-time error '1004' and when i click debug, this code is highlighted in yellow

Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True